# Qt Duplicate/Clone screens in RPI4

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qtquick2, raspberry-pi4

Im trying to duplicate my output screen from 'HDMI1' to 'HDMI2' on RPI4 device.
According to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html since Qt 5.11 it is possible using a kms configuration file.
So i build two Qt version for this purpose, 5.12.11 and 5.15.2.
here is the kms configuration i used:

```
{
 "device": "/dev/dri/card1",
  "outputs": [ 
                { "name": "HDMI1", "mode":"1024x600" },
                { "name": "HDMI2", "clones": "HDMI1" } 
             ]
}
```

The output is two screen showing the same window but the performance is very poor and the screen keep showing white frames while showing the application window.

And also the output keep saying:

```
QEGLPlatformContext: eglSwapBuffers failed: 3003
Could not lock GBM surface front buffer!
```

Also worth mentioning that when i use the application without the cloning feature it works just fine.
I Wonder if im doing something wrong.

Comment: You could need to configure some [Xorg](https://www.x.org/) server appropriately

Comment: I use EGLFS backend because xserver doesn't support hw acceleration.

Comment: Hi @MeHrAnMD any news on this? How you fixed the issue? I'm in the same situation, with the same error.